# sharepoint web service , getListItems, parameter mismatch

Tags: xml, sharepoint, soap, caml

I am using the getListItems of the sharepoint webservice, and when I don't specify a query it works fine. However, my problem is, visual studio 2010 is telling me the format for the xml parameters must be xmlElements, but the Microsoft API says they are xmlNodes.

When I try with xmlElements, I get a soap exception back.
When I try with xmlNodes, I get build errors.

i know my caml is fine, I used and tested it with caml builder.

Thanks in advance if anyone can help clear this up.

Comment: Posting the code you're talking about would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

kindly go through the following blogpost with sample code from which you can take help on how to get list items using webservice

http://sarangasl.blogspot.com/2009/12/sharepoint-list-web-service.html